# Problem Connecting SQLServer2016x64 using LinkedServer to MySqlx32

Tags: mysql, sql-server, odbc

Problem Connecting SQLServer2016x64 using LinkedServer to MySqlx32

I'm migrating a working system from Windows2003x32 with SQL2005x32 and MySqlx32 to Win2012R2x64 with SQL2016SP3x64 and MySqlx32
on the old system back I am still sucesfully using LinkedServer to read and write to MySql from SQL. With MySql ODBC 3.51 Dreiver.

On the new server I tryed a bunch of options all resulting in DSN architecture mismatch.

What I did:
I installed MySql-connector-odbc-3.51.30-win64 (later I tryed v5.1.13 and 5.3.14 both 32 and 64 versions)
Using odbcad32.exe from System32 and/or SysWOW64 (tryed both) I sucefully added under System DSN the datasource and tested Ok.

From SQLServerManager I tryed to add linked server using

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server='SVTPASS', @srvproduct='SVTPASS', @datasrc='SVTPASS',
@provider='MSDASQL',
@provstr='DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=LOCALHOST; Port=3333; USER=******; PASSWORD=********; OPTION=3; DATABASE=svt_fpc_auth'
```

later tryed using "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver}" and "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}"

But the strange thing is that whatever I try, even writing nonsense at DRIVER={} the same architecture mismatch error I get.

When testing the connection of linked server I recieve the following error:
"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"

where am I doing it wrong?
I know that I'm trying to acess a 32bit MySql from 64bit SQLServer but there should be a solution.

I read many forum posts about this issue and tryed a few options suggested here and there, but I'm confused and and I don/t even know now what combinations I tryed and what I didn't tryed yet.

Can someone help with at least telling what are the right weapons to use to fight this issue...
Thanks in andvance

Comment: Curious why you are going from a system that is well out of support to another one that will be out of support in another year or two. That goes for both Windows and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem
I new that I had to create the DSN from 64 version of odbcad32 but
The problem was that I was trying to launch odbcad32.exe from SysWOW64 folder but it launched an created the DSN in 32 bit state. Only when I launched it from windows apps it worked and created the DSN in 64 bit.

thanks aniway

I don't know what to do with this thread/question in this case. please advise